# 2004 Mercury Marquis LS A/C & fan problems

Tags: ac, mercury, grand-marquis

My 04 Mercury Grand Marquis auto temp controlled A/C was working fine last night when I parked it. I got in it today, and it has no fan speeds at all, and the compressor is kicking on and off. I'm not having anything coming from the vents?

Answer (score 2):

This is more than likely the resistor pack which is on most vehicles, is located in the air box with the blower fan under your passenger side foot well. It should look something like this for your car:

[image: Pulled From RockAuto.com]
[image: Pulled From RockAuto.com]

Comment: @Paulster2 This is a nitpick, but technically with the auto temp control there is no resistor pack. It's a fan controller and it's on the passenger side of the firewall behind the coolant lines for the heater core.